# C# catch dialog box

Tags: c#

Is it possible to cach dialog boxes using C#?
For example I would like to create some kind of "auto OK klicker"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

http://www.codeplex.com/white

It's a library of useful functions for launching GUI applications, finding controls on their windows and dialog boxes and sending messages to them.

Comment: that's awesome. mark this as the right answer. ignore mine completely. AHK will work, but I can't tell you how much the syntax blows compared to C#.

Answer (score 0):

For your own application or for all applications?

For a general system-wide thing, you'd need to monitor all the open windows handles. There are Win32 API calls for this. Then you'd have to use another API call SendMessage to send the ENTER key to that dialog, and hope that OK was the default button.

A cheap hack if you have a particular application in mind is AutoHotKey. You can use it's spy tool to get the class name of the dialog you're interested in, and use WinWait, or WinWaitActivate to see when it pops up and then the Send command to send the ENTER key.

Like I said, that will work if you have a(or a few) particular apps you're interested, because it depends on the class, or the window text of the dialog.